# Anaconda Package error, on starting Sublime Text-3

Tags: python, windows, sublimetext3, anaconda

[image: Error in Sublime Text-3 due to Anaconda]

**Text editor**: Sublime Text-3

**OS**: Windows-10

**Package**:  [Anaconda](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/)

For Python I use: **Anaconda3-4.2.0**-Windows-x86_64

**Problem**:

Every time I open my Sublime Text-3, this error pop-up. Although I think it does not effect the functionality of Anaconda Package, at times it is quite irritating.

**Background**:

As I have to work with few libraries of python( data science) I prefer Anaconda, as I don't have to install all the packages separately. But I don't have much experience with it. Normally when I use Python, it is added to my Path also, but in case of Anaconda I think it adds it separately as I was not able to find any separate bin file for python to add in Path. But I am able to access Python-3 from command prompt, so I guess it is configured correctly.

**User Variable:**

[image]

**Issues**: [Anaconda Issue on github](https://github.com/DamnWidget/anaconda/issues/527)

I tried few fixes, but no luck. I am not really able to understand why does it need to use local host, as it doesn't seem relevant.

**Anaconda Configuration:**

[image: Default Configuration]

**If some one had faced similar issue or have any idea regarding it, then please explain how to fix this issue.**

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to the folder where Python is stored. (more details for Windows users in sub list)

   1.1. In the search bar type python

   1.2. Right click on the python app

   1.3. Select folder location
2. Right click on your python .exe file
3. Select Properties
4. Copy destiny **path**, it could look like this: "C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe"
5. Open Sublime Text
6. Select Preferences/Package Settings/Anaconda/Settings - User
7. Change python interpreter, as per: "python_interpreter": "paste here the **path**"

This is how I solved it, I hope it works for you too!!

Comment: That solves it for me too (I had the same problem under Linux). thanks. However, is there a way in which I can make the python_interpreter dependent on the actual anaconda environment that is active?

Answer (score 1):

In your anaconda configuration file, under python_interpreter, replace "python" with the actual location of your python executable. For example: "C:/Users/USERNAME/python"

You can find the location of the executable fairly easily by searching python in windows 10 search bar, then opening up the folder location. This will take you to the shortcut location, right click on the shortcut, properties, open file location. That should take you to where the executable is located. Copy the location and paste it as shown above. Make sure you're using forward slashes and you include python in the location as shown above.

Comment: `where python` from the command prompt also works to find the path (and also works for finding the Python store app, which can be harder to find).  Forward slashes are not a must.  Back slashes work just as well but you need to remember to escape them with an extra back slash in Python strings.

Answer (score 1):

Enter the following code in the sublime console:

```
import socket; socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM).connect(("localhost", 50390))
```

The error should no longer appear.

Answer (score 0):

If the anaconda still works fine after this error message then go to

> Preferences -> Package settings -> Anaconda -> Settings-Default

find "swallow_startup_errors" and set it "true".

Comment: Please explain why this would resolve the question and what that setting is controlling.